# Zsh: quickly bookmark commands

Tags: zsh, command-history

I just had an idea, I'm sure it must exist though I could not find anything on the web.
This topic gets close to my idea but not enough:
[How to quickly store and access often used commands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26245/how-to-quickly-store-and-access-often-used-commands)

I'd like to have a `.bookmark.zsh` file in which I store commands, not often used (I could create an alias for these), but more those which were a pain in the ass to write down, and that I could use some other times.

Like I just typed:

```
rake db:drop --trace && echo 'dropped' && \
  rake db:create --trace && echo 'created' && \
  rake db:migrate --trace && echo 'migrated' && \
  rake db:seed --trace && echo 'seed'
```

And I want to save it, so I type `bm -save 'description'` and it adds

```
rake db:drop --trace && echo 'dropped' && \
  rake db:create --trace && echo 'created' && \
  rake db:migrate --trace && echo 'migrated' && \
  rake db:seed --trace && echo 'seed' # description`
```

in my `.bookmark.zsh` file.

And then I can do `bm -find 'description'` (or ideally 'descr' 'desc' etc.) and I find the command back.

Like bookmarks work!

I'm pretty bad at shell so any tip would be super nicely welcomed!

Comment: I just posted a zsh version of the 'bashtags' solution found in your link. If that's suitable, it's essentially just typing `$_description` (with the caveat that spaces are not permitted -- use _ instead) at the end of the command. Then you can just Ctrl+R and type `$_description` to get it back. This exploits the fact that undefined variables expand to nothing.