# Vocabulary trainer for Unix

Tags: linux, dictionary

I am looking for a Linux (Ubuntu) software that allows me to take note of new words that I learn online.

I manually add new words, their meaning and usage. The software then displays each item in a nice format and allows me to review them in a variety of ways, e.g., randomly, or just alphabetically.

It is also good to have the ability to export the list to a file, for use in other software.

It's something like a box of vocabulary cards, but hopefully with some additional useful capabilities.

Comment: Crude DIY version: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138720/how-can-i-view-a-reference-or-cheat-sheet-of-the-basic-bash-syntax-in-the-linux/138727#138727

Answer (score 4):

I can recommend [Anki](http://ankisrs.net/). You can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install anki
```

Anki has the option to store the words that you learn in an online account, allowing you to work on different computers (or your phone as it also runs on iOS and Android besides Linux, Windows and OSX), without having to transfer data back and forth. There is also a multitude of dataset to download, in case you want to practise something without typing in (a good exercise in itself) things beforehand yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [`parley`](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=66741) and [`openteacher`](http://www.unixmen.com/openteacher-improve-foreign-language-vocabulary-skills/).

Here's also a [list of best flashcard tools](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20100629145905781/Flashcard.html) for Linux.